# excel VBA Coding to autmatically name sheets from a pivot drop down

Tags: excel, pivot, drilldown, vba

I have just started using VBA and am looking for a script that will automatically name the new sheet created by a pivot drill down according to what I have drilled down. For simplicity's sake my pivot has 2 columns. Name and Amount. I will double click on the amount to generate the drill down and want it to automatically name the new sheet with the appropriate name. Edit: I have tried the below code (pasting to ThisWorkbook tab) and receive a "Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch" @ the line:

```
If SheetExists(SheetName) Then
```

Looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim shtCur As Worksheet
Set shtCur = ActiveSheet

Sheets("Pivot Sheet Name").Select
RN = ActiveCell.Row
CN = ActiveCell.Column
SheetName = Cells(RN, 1).Value 


If SheetExists(SheetName) Then
    Worksheets(SheetName).Select
Else

    shtCur.Move _
        After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    shtCur.Name = "SheetName"
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Function SheetExists(wsName As String, Optional wb As Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean

SheetExists = False
Dim WS As Worksheet

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
Set WS = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not WS Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True

End Function
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Ken, not my intention to use this as a code writing service and certainly not my intention to treat other users as "code monkeys". I have looked and trialled solutions detailed on the net all morning but have made little progress. Other similar threads have been dormant for a while so I thought to start a new one. I will reword my question to sound more compliant. Cheers.

Comment: Much better. Thanks! However, you say *I get an error*; it would help if you indicated where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either declare `sheetname` to be a string in your `Workbook_NewSheet` event (i.e. `Dim sheetname As String`), or change `wsName` to be passed `ByVal` in your `SheetExists` function (i.e. `ByVal wsName As String`) or, preferably, do both.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim shtCur As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim RN As Long
    Dim CN As Long
    Set shtCur = ActiveSheet

    Sheets("Pivot Sheet Name").Select
    RN = ActiveCell.Row
    CN = ActiveCell.Column
    SheetName = Cells(RN, 1).Value    

    If SheetExists(SheetName) Then
        Worksheets(SheetName).Select ' This probably will be confusing to users
                                     ' as it means that the sheet that was just
                                     ' created will not be being shown
    Else    
        shtCur.Move _
            After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        'This line was setting the sheet name to be "SheetName"
        'shtCur.Name = "SheetName"
        shtCur.Name = SheetName
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function SheetExists(ByVal wsName As String, Optional wb As Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WS = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    SheetExists = Not WS Is Nothing    
End Function
```